# How to activate GRASS 7 v2 in QGIS 2.18 on Mac

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-2, grass-7.0

I have QGIS installed. I've ticked `GRASS 7` in `Plugins/Manage and Install plugins`, but the Grass Tools options are all greyed out with `No mapset is open` reported.  In the GRASS options the `New Mapset` is also greyed out.

Couple of other questions on this relating to Windows.  Nothing obvious for Mac.

Comment: Do you have installed GRASS 7 standalone?

Comment: Nope. I understood it was baked into the 2.18 build.

Comment: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis --> " QGIS 2.18.9-1 ...
QGIS includes its own internal copies of GRASS, Orfeo Toolbox, SAGA and TauDEM. "   -- seems to be included.